# How to simulate countdown that shows the current time left in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have read about discord.ext.**tasks** but it just loops the particular code, but that is not what I wanted.

The user should be able to view remaining time and add time.

This is the current code:

```
class MyBot(Bot):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.time = timedelta()


bot = MyBot(command_prefix='.', case_insensitive=True)


@bot.command(name='seconds')
async def add_seconds(ctx: Context, seconds: int):
    bot.time += timedelta(seconds=seconds)


@bot.command(name='minutes')
async def add_minutes(ctx: Context, minutes: int):
    bot.time += timedelta(minutes=minutes)

# the user should be able to view the time left
@bot.command(name='time')
async def view_time_left(ctx: Context):
    await ctx.send(str(bot.time))
```

*How to manipulate the bot.time to start counting down?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run this through a [Cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html#ext-commands-cogs). You can create a task loop and set how often to repeat that task.

```
from discord.ext import tasks, commands
import asyncio

class countdown(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.time_left = 0
        self.countdown.start()

    # Add seconds and minutes
    @commands.command(name='seconds')
    async def add_seconds(self, ctx, sec:int=0):
        self.time_left += sec

    @commands.command(name='minutes')
    async def add_minutes(self, ctx, minutes:int=0):
        self.time_left += minutes*60

    # View time left, timeformat is just a way to display the time in 00:00 format
    # If you want hours (00:00:00) as well, you can add:
    # hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    # timeformat = "{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}".format(hours, minutes, seconds)
    @commands.command(name='time')
    async def view_time(self, ctx):
        if self.time_left == 0:
            print("00:00")
            await ctx.send("00:00")
        else:
            minutes, seconds = divmod(self.time_left, 60)
            timeformat = "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(minutes, seconds)
            message = await ctx.send(timeformat)
            i = 5
            while i>0:
                i -= 1
                minutes, seconds = divmod(self.time_left, 60)
                timeformat = "{:02d}:{:02d}".format(minutes, seconds)
                await message.edit(content=timeformat)
                await asyncio.sleep(1) # So it only does this every second
            await message.delete()


    # Loop this task every second, simply subtract 1 from time_left, if time_left>0
    @tasks.loop(seconds=1)
    async def countdown(self):
        if self.time_left>0:
            self.time_left -= 1
```

In the `view_time` function, anything that comes after `message = await ctx.send...` is strictly not necessary. I added it so the bot will edit the message it sends `i` times to show it counting down.

Comment: does it affect the performance if handling multiple data every seconds? for example, handling an array of time_left using tasks?.

Comment: I haven't really tested, depends on how many you want to run? I had this run for 10 minutes while spamming different commands and i can't say I noticed any performance drop